# Why is the stock price so different between XTB and Yahoo?

Tags: yahoo-finance

When using XTB and looking for the stock of *Lancashire Holdings Limited* (LRE.UK) the price is about 6.39. Now when looking at the same stock in [Yahoo Finance](https://fr.finance.yahoo.com/quote/LRE.L?p=LRE.L) (LRE.L) I see the price is about 641.

Even is one price is given in EUR and the other price in GBP, that cannot explain the difference of a factor of 100.

So what is the correct price for a stock of *Lancashire Holdings Limited*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UK stock prices are conventionally quoted in pence, not whole pounds. Many of the aggregator sites either don't take account of this or bury the explanation a bit - in this case Yahoo specify that "Devise en GBp" - ie price is in GBp, which is not *quite* the same as GBP. GBP = pounds, [GBp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_sterling) = pence. (You may also see "GBX" used for this, as GBp is quite confusing...). As a general rule, any time a stock price seems off by a factor of 100x, this is probably the reason!

In this case, the price as quoted by Yahoo is 641 pence (GBp), or 6.41 pounds (GBP). The price quoted by XTB is 6.39 pounds (GBP). The small remaining difference is probably due to delays in how they're updated and exactly which data source they use.